# About Locale class in Java

Tags: java, android, locale, text-to-speech

I'm using a TTS method on Android which takes a `Locale` instance as an argument. So I googled the class `Locale` and found some example code. But I don't understand what is different among usages below because I tested them all with a TTS method and it seems to work all the same to me.

```
Locale("ja")
Locale("ja_JP")
Locale("ja", "JP", "")
Locale.JAPAN
Locale.JAPANESE
```

Are there any differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the Locale class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) describes this in (almost excruciating) detail. The valid language, country, and variant codes are described in [ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639).

Here are the differences between the five examples you give:

- `ja` simply describes the Japanese language with no country.
- `ja_JP` specifies both the Japanese language and the country of Japan
- The three parameter constructor splits off the language, country, and variant into separate arguments. `Locale("ja", "JP", "")` is equivalent to `Locale("ja_JP")` since no variant is provided.
- [`Locale.JAPAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#JAPAN) is a constant shortcut for `ja_JP` (the country of Japan).
- [`Locale.JAPANESE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#JAPANESE) is a constant shortcut for `ja` (the Japanese language).

What does this all mean? Well, it depends on where it is used. Locales are used with a number of different APIs, including the date-time APIs, text-to-speech APIs, and more.

In the context of text-to-speech, the locale can be used in a number of ways, such as:

- Selecting the appropriate voice to use
- Applying the proper inflection for certain words. Different locales may speak the same word in the same language differently.
- Translating certain non-words into speech. For instance, different locales may speak numbers or fractions differently.

In general, you want to be as specific and accurate as possible when selecting a Locale.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me a lot!!